# How to update only master in a set of working repositories?

Tags: git, scripting, zsh

I'm creating a script (zsh) to update from remote the master branch *only*, in a set of local repositories.
The development is ongoing in different branches, but I'd like to update only **master branch** from remote. I will manually deal with merge conflicts later on.
In a folder, the script would:

1. identify the git repo(s)
2. get into the local repo(s)
3. identify the remote HEAD (usually *master* or *main*, but not necessarily)
4. checkout local master
5. git pull from remote
6. checkout back into the working (untouched by the script) branch
7. move to another repo

Is this the only possible workflow or maybe is there a more proper git command/workflow?
To be clear I just wish the local master to be as much up to date as possible while working on other stuff. If I could avoid checking in and out every time, that is a plus.
thanks

Comment: Why not checkout local main/master rather than the remote branch?

Comment: actually that's right, I wrote it wrong: it will checkout local master and then git pull :) let me fix it

Answer (score 0):

> **To be clear I just wish the local master to be as much up to date as**
> **possible while working on other stuff.**

To acheive the above , you can use `git alias` , git feature which allows to define a alias for a one/many commands which you can run.

Eg : You can configure an alias in git .

eg :`git config --global alias.start '!git checkout master && git pull origin master'` .

This should checkout your local master , pull the latest changes inside the master automatically .

Everytime now you execute command `git start` , git will checkout your local master and then update latest changes from remote `master`

Comment: that could potentially simplify the script, but I cannot be sure on which branch HEAD will point to, so I'll have to put some parameters as well